# How to circle multiple cells? (special case)

Tags: tables, circles

I need to circle multiple cells, on different rows/columns. This is a problem which has been solved.

However, I have a more particular case of the problem. I need to draw a circle that needs to illustrate that the elements of the last row are together with the ones of the first row, resulting in a matrix like in the example.

Here is the way I have implemented the table:

```
\begin{tabular}{c c|c|c|c|c|}
    \multirow{7}{*}{\parbox{1.5cm}{$DataQ_2$}}
    & \multicolumn{5}{c}{$Q_1Q_0$} \\
    \cline{3-6}
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & 00 & 01 & 11 & 10 \\ 
    \cline{2-6}
    & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{00} & X & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{01} & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{11} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{10} & X & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
    \cline{2-6}
\end{tabular}
```

This is the way it looks: 
[image: Table now]

This is how I want it to look(sorry for the shitty drawing quality... I hope it's obvious that I want though):
[image: Table as it should be]

PS If you tell me a more elegant way to implement the table to look like this, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option is to use the [`tikzmark`](http://www.ctan.org/pjkg/tikzmark) library (from TikZ) to place some marks and then to use those marks to draw the frames; one possibility (adjust the settings according to your needs):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{}\multirow{7}{*}{$\text{Data}Q_2$}
     & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Q_1Q_0} \\
    \cline{3-6}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & & 00 & 01 & 11 & 10 \\ 
    \cline{2-6}
    & 00 & \tikzmark{startup}X & 1 & 1 & 1\tikzmark{endup} \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & 01 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & 11 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & 10 & \tikzmark{startdown}X & 1 & 1 & 0\tikzmark{enddown} \\
    \cline{2-6}
\end{array}
\]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\foreach \Val in {up,down}
{
\draw[rounded corners,red,thick]
  ([shift={(-0.5\tabcolsep,-0.5ex)}]pic cs:start\Val) 
    rectangle 
  ([shift={(0.5\tabcolsep,2ex)}]pic cs:end\Val);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If the boxes should have one end open:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\text{Data}Q_2\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{}
     & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Q_1Q_0} \\
    \cline{3-6}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & & 00 & 01 & 11 & 10 \\ 
    \cline{2-6}
    & 00 & \tikzmark{startup}X & 1 & 1 & 1\tikzmark{endup} \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & 01 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & 11 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & 10 & \tikzmark{startdown}X & 1 & 1 & 0\tikzmark{enddown} \\
    \cline{2-6}
\end{array}
\]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[rounded corners,red,thick]
  ([shift={(-0.5\tabcolsep,2ex)}]pic cs:startup) -- 
  ++(0,-2.6ex) -- 
  ([shift={(0.5\tabcolsep,-0.6ex)}]pic cs:endup) --
  ++(0,2.6ex);
\draw[rounded corners,red,thick]
  ([shift={(-0.5\tabcolsep,-0.8ex)}]pic cs:startdown) -- 
  ++(0,2.8ex) -- 
  ([shift={(0.5\tabcolsep,2ex)}]pic cs:enddown) --
  ++(0,-2.8ex);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Remarks:

- Since some internal calculations are involved, the code needs two runs to stabilize.
- Since the content of the table is mostly maths, I change to `array` instead of `tabular`.
- I used

  ```
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
  ```

  to have some more "air" around the cell content.
- In the second example code I suppressed the \multirow and simply placed `\text{Data}Q_2` next to the `array`.

Comment: My impression is that the upper oval should be open at the top and the lower one open at the bottom.

Comment: @egreg I'll provide this option in some seconds.

Comment: @egreg You are right, the upper oval has to be open at the top and the lower open at the bottom. The same is correct assuming that this is done for the leftmost column and the rightmost one.

Thank you, @GonzaloMedina!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina By the way, `\multirow` is completely superfluous here: just place `\text{Data}Q_{2}\quad` next to the array.

Comment: @RaduSzasz I've provided an option with open shapes.

Comment: @egreg Answer updated :) Regarding the \multirow, placing just the text next to the `array` instead of the `\multirow`, some  `\raisebox` will have to be used in that case to correct the vertical placement, so (in this case), I think `\multirow` can be used.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I don't think so, but I don't insist. Surely the `\parbox` is superfluous, isn't it?

Comment: @egreg Yes, that is superfluous; I'll remove it. Thanks.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Works great! If you don't mind, and you have the time, it would be really useful to explain the arguments that you use when creating the ovals, as I have to use this multiple places. Thank you!

Comment: @RaduSzasz You're welcome! I could add some brief explanations (but later, I have to leave now); in the meantime, since I used basic TikZ syntax, you can refer to the PGF/TikZ documentation.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I am trying to make the ovals to the left and right, as to show the cover of this Karnaugh map. Could you help me?