# How to circle multiple cells? (special case 2)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, circles

I want to ask a question about a solution presented [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223731/how-to-circle-multiple-cells-special-case) from @GonzaloMedina but I cannot comment.

I want to draw the same type of open end and closed rounded rectangular but I want also to draw ovals with the right side open and I cannot figure out how to modify it.

[image]

The code he proposes for open top/bottom ends and i want to modify is :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\text{Data}Q_2\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{}
     & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Q_1Q_0} \\
    \cline{3-6}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & & 00 & 01 & 11 & 10 \\ 
    \cline{2-6}
    & 00 & \tikzmark{startup}X & 1 & 1 & 1\tikzmark{endup} \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & 01 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & 11 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & 10 & \tikzmark{startdown}X & 1 & 1 & 0\tikzmark{enddown} \\
    \cline{2-6}
\end{array}
\]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[rounded corners,red,thick]
  ([shift={(-0.5\tabcolsep,2ex)}]pic cs:startup) -- 
  ++(0,-2.6ex) -- 
  ([shift={(0.5\tabcolsep,-0.6ex)}]pic cs:endup) --
  ++(0,2.6ex);
\draw[rounded corners,red,thick]
  ([shift={(-0.5\tabcolsep,-0.8ex)}]pic cs:startdown) -- 
  ++(0,2.8ex) -- 
  ([shift={(0.5\tabcolsep,2ex)}]pic cs:enddown) --
  ++(0,-2.8ex);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: I think its a duplicate to [How to draw circles around multiple row cells and column cells](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139183/124842)

Comment: @Bobyandbob I agree that the question is a duplicate but that post does not contain (what I humbly suggest is) the best answer: a `matrix of nodes`.

Comment: @Andrew duplicates and different approaches are always a bit sticky business.  One might suggest adding your answer, instead, to the cited duplicate.  Or else leave it here to get the upvotes it deserves.  I've certainly had answers oft upvoted on questions deemed duplicates.  Please take no offense.  It will be linked to the other question.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes None taken:) It's clearly a duplicate and should be marked as such.

Comment: I have already read that post and it did not help me with my case. I alrady use the solution of the other previous post I cited, but I need it to be open on the right side. That is why i re-posted the solution that i need to some how change. If that is still considered a repost, I am sorry but i couldn't comment on the original solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `matrix of math nodes` (actually, a `matrix of nodes` is enough here...). In my experience this is by far the easiest way to "deocrate" matrices or, more generally, anything displayed on a grid.

For the reasons explained in the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) manual I would omit the vertical and horizontal rules and draw this as:

[image]

If you really want the lines they are easy to add either using a `\foreach` loop or, as is (now) done below, by styling each of the nodes in the `\matrix` as a rectangle with a specified minimum height and width:

[image]
Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}[ell/.style={red,very thick},
                       lines/.style={blue!0.5!black, thick},
                   nodes={anchor=center,rectangle, minimum width=6mm, minimum height=6mm, inner sep=0mm},
                       ]
       \matrix (M)[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells
       ]{
             & 00 & 01 & 11 & 10 \\
          00 & X  & 1  & 1  & 1 \\
          01 & 0  & 1  & 1  & 0 \\
          11 & 1  & 1  & 1  & 1 \\
          10 & X  & 1  & 1  & 0\\
       };
       \draw[lines](M-2-1.north west)--(M-2-5.north east);
       \draw[lines](M-1-2.north west)--(M-5-2.south west);
       \clip (M-1-1.north west) rectangle (M-5-5.south east);
       \draw[ell] (M-2-4) ellipse [x radius=0.9,y radius=0.19];
       \draw[ell](M-3-5) ellipse[x radius=0.9, y radius=0.19];
   \end{tikzpicture}

   \begin{tikzpicture}[ell/.style={red,very thick},
                    lines/.style={blue!0.5!black, thick},
                    emp/.style={draw=white}]
       \matrix (M)[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,
                   nodes={anchor=center,draw,rectangle, minimum width=6mm, minimum height=6mm, inner sep=0mm},
       ]{
       |[emp]| & 00 & 01 & 11 & 10\\
            00 & X  & 1  & 1  & 1 \\
            01 & 0  & 1  & 1  & 0 \\
            11 & 1  & 1  & 1  & 1 \\
            10 & X  & 1  & 1  & 0 \\
       };
       \clip (M-1-1.north west) rectangle (M-5-5.south east);
       \draw[ell] (M-2-4) ellipse [x radius=0.9,y radius=0.19];
       \draw[ell](M-3-5) ellipse[x radius=0.9, y radius=0.19];
   \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The `(M)` after `\matrix` means that the nodes have labels `(M-1-2)`, `(M-1-4)` etc. in the non-empty cells (with the option `nodes in empty cells` you can have nodes in the empty cells too). You can change `(M)` to anything you like. For more details see section 57.1 of the tikz manual.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but i want specifically the oval/rounded rectangular to be open on the right side. The provided table is just an example (i do not want to use it for karnaugh maps). Think of it as fixed sized blocks for example blocks of size 3. When the block is place at the end cells i want the drawing to show that its not a 2-cell block but in fact an incomplete block. That's why i want the  the drawing to be open as shown in the other post, but open on the right and not at the bottom/top.

Comment: @lightbird Sorry, I should have noticed as this is clearly part of your question. Doing what you actually asked for is even easier: just draw the ellipse after clipping the drawing area to the inside of the table. I'll edit my answer. I'll also fix up the lines so that they are straight...which, it turns out, simplified the code in the second example as I now draw the lines using `draw,rectangle` for each node in the `\matrix`.

Comment: @lightbird I've also just removed the rectangle from the `(1,1)` cell in the second example, since this does not appear in the OP.

Comment: @lightbird If Andrew's answer is a wholly satisfactory answer to your question, you should click the check mark to the left of his answer.  That is called "accepting" the answer and will indicate to other readers that this answer addressed your issue in the best way.

Comment: Well although it looks like a good solution, in my case i have to rewrite a very large table that is already in tabular environment, where the tikzpicture works just fine and the only think missing is the opening on the right side...

Comment: @lightbird  A `tikz` matrix has the same formatting as a `tabular` environment except that it starts with `\begin{tikzpicture}`, has some styling, and then ends with `\end{tikzpicture}`. So, there's really not very much editing that is required....although it sounds like you have added `\tikzmark{...}` in many place but you could just leave these where they are if you wanted because they won't cause any harm. This said, my code does your "opening right side" by clipping, so you should be able to add a suitable `\clip` command to your code to get what you want.